# No LVIF_TEXT in LVN_GETDISPINFO message using LVS_OWNERDATA mode

Tags: c++, mfc

I've encountered strange behavior in **MFC** when using **list control** (`CListCtrl`) with `LVS_REPORT` style in **"virtual mode"** i.e. with `LVS_OWNERDATA` style. List view itself is placed on a modeless dialog.

In dialog's `OnInitDialog` method I add two columns -- "Column 1" and "Column 2" in two different ways -- using `LVCOLUMN` and `ListView_InsertColumn` macro **(1)** and using `CHeaderCtrl` class with `HDITEM` structure **(2)**.

When using first method **(1)**, in `LVN_GETDISPINFO` message handler (message is handled by dialog, simple `ON_NOTIFY`) I receive a mask (`NMLVDISPINFO.item.mask` member) with different bits set (`LVIF_TEXT`, `LVIF_IMAGE`, `LVIF_STATE`, `LVIF_INDENT` etc.), after filling appropriate fields in `NMLVDISPINFO.item` structure, everything works fine.

But, when using second method **(2)** involving `CHeaderCtrl` class, the only bit in mask that is set is `LVIF_INDENT`, I never receive mask with anything else set.

Here are pieces of code that I use to add those columns:

**Method one (1):**

```
LVCOLUMN col;
col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
col.pszText = _T("Column 1");
col.cx = 100;

ListView_InsertColumn(m_MyList, 0, &col); //m_MyList is of CListCtrl type

col.pszText = _T("Column 2");
ListView_InsertColumn(m_MyList, 1, &col);
```

**And method two (2):**

```
HDITEM hdItem;
hdItem.mask = HDI_TEXT | HDI_FORMAT | HDI_WIDTH;
hdItem.fmt = HDF_STRING;
hdItem.cxy = 100;

hdItem.pszText = _T("Column 1");
hdItem.cchTextMax = _tcslen(hdItem.pszText);
m_MyList.GetHeaderCtrl()->InsertItem(0, &hdItem);

others_info.pszText = _T("Column 2");
others_info.cchTextMax = _tcslen(hdItem.pszText);
m_MyList.GetHeaderCtrl()->InsertItem(1, &hdItem);
```

What could possibly cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 is incorrectly using others_info for some operations but not others. It looks like the first InsertItem is using a text length that is possibly 0.  The second call to InsertItem reuses the same hdItem structure which hasn't been changed since the first call.

Comment: Good catch, but I need to apologize, `others_info` is a mistype, I've corrected the code. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.